# How can I mutate a column depending on another entry in the same row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my very first question and I just recently started with R so please be gentle with me.

I'm trying to perform multiple t-tests for each month / month before to check wether ratings have improved significantly. My data is a table with two columns: rating (1-10) and month (like 202103 for march 2021).

I would like to add an extra column named "p_value" which contains the p_value of a t-test (for the month displayed in "month" in each specific row and the month before).

I try to do this like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)

rating <- sample(x = 1:10, size = 200, replace = TRUE)
month <- sample(x = 202001:202012, size = 200, replace = TRUE)

mydata <- data.frame(month, rating)

mydata_with_p_value <- mydata %>%
  mutate(p_value = t.test(rating ~ month, data = (mydata %>% filter(month == 202001 | month == 202002)))$p.value)
```

I have no idea how to reference the "month" entry of the specific row which is mutated. I want to replace "month == 202001" with "month == MONTH_IN_THIS_ROW" and "month == 202002" with "MONTH_IN_THIS_ROW -1".

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: No one can run this except you since the input and library statements are missing. Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page regarding asking questions.

Comment: To get started with asking questions, have a look at this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use this workflow :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

mydata %>%
  mutate(new_month = as.yearmon(as.character(month), '%Y%m')) %>%
  arrange(new_month) %>%
  group_by(new_month) %>%
  nest() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(last_rating = lag(data), 
         p_value = map2_dbl(data, last_rating, 
                   ~t.test(rating,month, data = rbind(.x, .y))$p.value))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but the code doesn't workt for me as it returns p_values of 0 only, even if there is clear correlation.